# Membership Renewal from CiviCRM user dashboard error

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, civimember, user-dashboard

Civi 5.10.4 - Wordpress 5.1

We have set up that when users login, they are automatically forwarded to a wordpress page called User Dashboard - where we embedded a shortcode for their CiviCRM dashboard to populate. There is a link on that civicrm dashboard page to "renew now" for those with expired memberships- but it links to a contribution page that we no longer use for membership.

```
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.The page you requested is currently unavailable.
```

The default membership contribution page is setup correctly too.  This seems to only happen to those users that became members with the old contribution page - if they go to the new contribution page to process their membership renewal - it works out fine.

Is there anyway to redirect links to the old contribution page to the new contribution page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This extension may sort out part of your problem - [Disabled Page Redirect](https://civicrm.org/extensions/disabled-page-redirect)

Comment: This is great - also helps with all the disabled contribution pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can do redirects at the web server level - e.g. with `mod_rewrite` if you're using Apache.  I would assume that the [Redirection plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) for WordPress would also work.